# Why does Windows require CTRL+ALT+DEL to Logon?

Tags: windows, keyboard, login, ctrl-alt-delete

Has Microsoft ever offered an explanation for why they require <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to login?  (Yes I know you can disable it, but it is still their *preferred* method.)  It seems like at one point I heard that it was for security since you knew nothing else could trap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, but I've written programs that trap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, and it isn't that difficult, so I am pretty sure that was just a myth, either that or the decision to require <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> is based on a fallacy.

Either way, I am curious if there is an official reason, and if that reason has any actual merit.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a well known key sequence by every Windows users

Comment: Before that, it was a well known key sequence for every MS-DOS user

Comment: How can you trap the ctrl+alt+del key? Even remote desktop or virtual machine softwares cannot do that and must implement an alternative for this

Comment: This question was re-asked as [What makes Secure Login (CTRL+ALT+DEL) Secure?](http://superuser.com/q/901892/354511), where it got pretty much the same answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the same as this Server Fault question: [How does CTRL-ALT-DEL to log in make Windows more secure?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2912/how-does-ctrl-alt-del-to-log-in-make-windows-more-secure).

Here is the [accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/2914/10448) from there, by [Oskar Duveborn](https://serverfault.com/users/1463/oskar-duveborn):

> The Windows (NT) kernel is designed to reserve the notification of
>   this key combination to a single process: **Winlogon**. So, as long as the
>   Windows installation itself is working as it should - no third party
>   application can respond to this key combination (if it could, it could
>   present a fake logon window and keylog your password ;)